# Custom Fonts in SwiftUI

Tags: fonts, swiftui

I have downloaded a couple of .TTF's and added them as resources. Then added the "Fonts provided by application" array type key to the info.plist, then added the font names as elements. However, The fonts are not showing up in the app. Below is my code. Am I doing something wrong?

```
struct ContentView: View { 
     var body: some View { 
         Text("Hello World").font(.custom("DaddyRewind", size: 36)) 
     }
 }
```

Comment: I had the same problem because I was uploading the folder with fonts file in it. What I did was adding all the fonts and collect them later with a group folder. The problem was that adding fonts already inside a folder doesn’t make a copy on Bundle resources

Answer (score 1):

Add Your Fonts
[image]

Add Your Fonts to the Info.plist
[image]

Then

```
.font(.custom("Your-Font-Name", size: 48))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only difference between what you have suggested and what I have already done is that you put you fonts in a "Fonts" folder, where I put mine in a "Resources" folder. Do you think that makes a difference?

Comment: @Grepler it should be the same

Comment: OK, I changed my config to replicate yours and my custom fonts still are not showing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: have you set the right font names (casesensetive) in Info.plist and the right key **Fonts provided by application**?

Comment: Yes. Everything is exactly the same as your config. Spelling is correct.

Comment: Follow [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/swiftui-basics-importing-custom-fonts-b6396d17424d)

Comment: New development. If I use one of the native custom fonts  like Georgia or Verdana it works fine. But if I import TTF’s the system is buggy at best. Sometimes they work, somwtimes they do not.